# Linux Mint with EFI, Windows 10 with MBR

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint, efi

Long story short, I now have two drives in my PC:

- /dev/nvme0n1 - Linux mint installation, EFI boot. Primary OS
- /dev/sda - Windows 10 installation, MBR boot. Secondary

The idea is, as you probably guessed, dual boot between these. However, To do this I have to change BIOS settings to turn EFI boot on and off - Legacy boot for windows, and EFI boot if I want to boot linux.

What's the simplest and least invasive way of dual booting between these two drives and OSes without having to change boot mode?

At the moment, it looks like grub never gets a say in the boot process, so I'm thinking that I probably need to use legacy boot for this.

---

PS: Not sure what more info about my system is relevant for a fix, so if anything is lacking, leave a comment, and i'll amend.

---

**Edit:**

I'm currently messing about with using grub2 the way i did way back, so grub2 is being loaded now. Now I'm working on chainloading to the Win10 partition, `/dev/sda2`. For the record, I have nothing against running both OSes on EFI, It's just that I've failed to get with the times and actually familiarize myself with how EFI works, and how to properly use it.

Comment: There is no such thing as GPT boot. Did you perhaps mean MBR?

Comment: @DanielB Yes. Edited accordingly. Ever since there was an alternative to MBR boot I always get the terminology mixed - MBR/GPT/EFI/UEFI =)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you’re not willing to have Windows also boot using UEFI? Because you could convert it using some manual work. Add rEFInd to the mix and you’ll even have a somewhat fancy OS selection menu.

Comment: @DanielB I have nothing against it, it just happens to be set up as legacy boot, as a result of an installation process that required me to use legacy boot there and then. If it's possible to change Win10 to EFI boot, that's acceptable too